# Adding filter for Spinner and filter the data on spinner itself

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a scenario where I want to filter the data when user types something.
I am using Spinner currently, but what I want is user should be able to write data on spinner itself and data gets filtered at run time. I am not able to find anything similar to what I want.

Something similar to below image (It is an example of RadcomboBox used in ASP.net).

[image]

Comment: Its better to use _AutoCompleteTextView_

Comment: [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: Using an AutoCompleteTextView would be a better way to do it.

In that case you can use an afterTextChangedListener and use the text at that time to filter the data from the list from which you populate the dropdown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that using Edittext and Listview
when you type in EditText box as per that Listview will refesh the data.
Consider initialty `ArrayList<String> Citylist` load  in `CityAdapter` like below code.

```
CityAdapter adapter = new CityAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.customlayout, Citylist );
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When you type in EditText Box listview will refresh data - use below code

```
     et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  }

                  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                  }

                  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                      if(!s.toString().equals(""))
                      {
                          filterlist = new ArrayList<String>();

                          filterlist=  getFilter(s.toString());
                           CityAdapter adapter = new CityAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.customlayout, filterlist);
                          listview.setAdapter(adapter); 


                          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      }
                      else
                      {
                           CityAdapter adapter = new CityAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.customlayout, Citylist);
                          listview.setAdapter(adapter); 
                          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      }

                  }
                  });
```

Listview filter function is below -

```
 public  ArrayList<String> getFilter(CharSequence charSequence)
        {
         ArrayList<String> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<String>();;
                 if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        for(String data : Citylist)
                        {
                            //In this loop, you'll filter through originalData and compare each item to charSequence.
                            //If you find a match, add it to your new ArrayList
                            //I'm not sure how you're going to do comparison, so you'll need to fill out this conditional
                            if(data.toLowerCase().contains(charSequence))
                            {
                                filterResultsData.add(data);
                            }
                        }            

                    }

                    return filterResultsData;
                }
```

Comment: I thought of that approach but listview contains lots of data, initially listview will be populated and large UI space will be consumed, so to avoid that I was thinking of using spinner or any other approach.

Comment: instead of spinner show button and when user click on button you can show custom alerDialog with the custom layout which contains EditText and Listview.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
 CustomAutoComplete autoComTextView = (CustomAutoComplete) view.findViewById(R.id.autoComTextView);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, myArray[1]);
        autoComTextView.setThreshold(1);
        autoComTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        autoComTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
                if (myArray[1].length > 0) {
                    if (!autoComTextView.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(null);
                    autoComTextView.showDropDown();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        autoComTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),myArray[0][position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

your view will be like this

```
            <com.package.name.CustomAutoComplete
                android:id="@+id/autoComTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
                android:textColor="@color/BLACK"/>
```

`CustomAutoComplete` class should by like this

```
public class CustomAutoComplete extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoComplete(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public CustomAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isPopupShowing()) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            if (inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findFocus().getWindowToken(),
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        Drawable dropdownIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp);
        if (dropdownIcon != null) {
            right = dropdownIcon;
            right.mutate().setAlpha(150);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            super.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        } else {
            super.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        }

    }

}
```